# How to remove the side bar from title frame in 'Goettingen' theme and center the contents of title page?

Tags: beamer

I am using the theme \usetheme{Goettingen}. When I use \begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage \end{frame}, the side bar disappears, but the contents are still in the same position and not centered.

Is it possible to keep a plain side bar without contents in this theme, or is it possible to center the contents, after removing the side bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can center the title page like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Goettingen}
\title{text}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[plain]
\hspace*{.5\beamersidebarwidth}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \titlepage
\end{minipage}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you would like to keep an empty sidebar:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Goettingen}
\title{text}


\begin{document}
    
\section{title}

{
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 
}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to run the first set of commands, but it is showing error.  The second set of commands-to remove the contents and keep the side bar- it works.. Thank you..

Comment: @LEKSHMINAIRK.B. Is your tex distribution up-tp-date? The `\beamersidebarwidth` macro was introduced in beamer v3.65. If you have an older version, you will get an error